# How to make new post show instantly in a View Display for the author who created it?

Tags: views, database

I have this Views Display (profile page) that shows the author's content. However for some reason whenever an author post a content, it does not show instantly in his Profile Views. Yet when you check his profile page as an anonymous user or other account, it's there instantly!

I'm completely astonished as this is weird for me. Is this a bug or I'm missing something?

Comment: Do you use caching in your views?

Comment: I do but even then... It does not worked this way. Any new post resets the render output showing the new content instantly to everyone. At least that's how it's suppose to work on Pantheon according to them. Another thing is aside from the author himself, the new post is instantly viewable by everyone! Really weird. Additional Info, I have entity cache open. I'm checking its bug/issue page if similar issue exist.

Comment: Maybe you can try by disabling the caching of your view (temporary) en check if this solves your problem. Then, at least you know if it's a caching problem or not.

Comment: I'll do that actually now.

Comment: Ok it works when there is no caching set in the specific views. Yet I still don't understand why does it show instantly to everyone except the author himself when caching is enabled.

Comment: Maybe you were caching per user? Then it is pretty obvious why it wouldn't work for the author

Comment: The view is a page, not a views block. I'm also inspecting entity cache module, varnish or redis cache. I'm still trying to find an issue similar to it. We do both agree that is definitely a caching mechanism that is causing it. I guess I need to read more books/article regarding debugging caching. :(

Comment: I think it is a bug or a problem with entity cache and views query results. Whenever the views query cache is set above 0 seconds. It doesn't update (no matter how long) for the author himself. Yet it is instantly visible to everyone... I check this using four different browser 2 auth users 1 admin and 1 anonymous.

Comment: yup its entity cache. i turned it off and everything update as it supposed to with views caching on.

Comment: Glad I could help to narrow down the problem :).

Comment: @Robin I'm always thankful for any help! Thank You and I appreciate your help!